# Style WindowsForms Project

Tags: winforms, datagridview, styles

I want to style my forms and some controls on my project, e.g. dataGridView.

I know, I can make a method like this an set it for every dataGridView.

```
    public static void StyleDataGridView(DataGridView dg)
    {
        dg.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        dg.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        ....
    }
```

My question: is there a possibility to do such style code only once in my project? How?

Comment: You can make custom user control that contains the controls which you want to use.  And you can customize controls in that user control. Instead of default datagridview you can use that custom user control. It will contain controls that you need as you designed.

Answer (score 0):

First step with userControl worked very well.
But how to handle the Click, DoubleClick and the CellMouseDown Event?

My code so far:

```
public partial class ucGridView : UserControl
{
    
    public object DataSource
    {
        get { return dataGridView.DataSource; }
        set { dataGridView.DataSource = value; }
    }

    public ucGridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).